# How to storyboard a combination of UITabBarController and sliding menu like MMDrawerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, slidingmenu

As an iOS noob, I recently starting feeling pretty good about myself when my iOS productivity started looking good. Until... I tried to figure out how to combine a UITabBarController with MMDrawerController in a storyboard :-(

The app shows three tabs permanently along the bottom, and I want to add a right-side sliding menu to that, and ideally I want to do this in storyboard. I settled on MMDrawerController for the sliding menu.

Question 1: **Is it even *possible* to point the first tab of the UITabBarController to a MMDrawerController?** Or should it be the other way around: set up the MMDrawerController at the root, and have the center view be the tabbed screen?

For example, UITabBarController has to be the root view of the application. So, I tried setting up the MMDrawerController for the view of the first tab (as that's where I need it only anyway), but I was just not able to get it to work at all. All examples of how to integrate MMDrawerController into your project that I could find online, all set up the MMDrawerController at the root. To set up a tabbed screen as a sub view, it looks like you can't use UITabBarController, but need to mimic that yourself with UITabBar and regular UIViewControllers?

Question 2: **Has anyone seen any examples or tutorials that combine a tabbed interface with the side sliding menu?**

The UI used in the Facebook iPhone app is essentially what I'm trying to employ here: you can drag the side sliding menu and as you do that it pushes out the main view along with its fixed tabs at the bottom.

I'm totally overwhelmed and confused. I have no idea how to attack this.  It also doesn't help that I'm totally new at Storyboards :-(

Any help, or just pointers are super appreciated...

Thanks,
Erik

Answer (score -2):

[here](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) is a good tutorial to implement a sliding menu like facebook.

Comment: Yes, beautifully done tutorial, and I believe I saw that before I settled on MMDrawerController. However, that tutorial also doesn't show how to have a UITabBarController that shows tabs at the bottom of the screen, and at the same time has a sliding menu that can push those tabs _off the screen_ That is what I'm after. Still haven't figured it out as I needed to move on to other things :-/

Comment: @ErikvanderNeut Did you get solution for this anyhow?

Comment: @RakeshSingh, no! :-( I gave up on it: instead, I'm having the drawer sliding open between the navigation bar at the top and the tab controls at the bottom.